# How to verify HttpResponseRedirect is to an external site?

Tags: python, django

I'm using the following middleware snippet:

```
class AjaxRedirect(object):
    """
    Instead of returning a 302 for AJAX requests, instead we should return a 200 with a location
    to redirect to so jQuery can forward the user as needed.
    """

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.is_ajax():
            if type(response) == HttpResponseRedirect:
                logger.warn(response.__dict__)
                redirect = '%s&ajaxRedirect=1' % response['Location']
                logger.info('Returned AjaxRedirect to %s' % redirect)
                return HttpResponse(
                    json.dumps(
                        {'redirect': redirect},
                        indent=4,
                        sort_keys=False),
                    content_type='application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        return response
```

However if the redirect is to an external site I would like to forego the query string parameter. Is there a reliable way to find this information given I have both the `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponseRedirect` instances?

**SOLUTION**

Add the following check:

```
if request.get_host() in redirect or not redirect.startswith('http'):
    redirect = '%s&ajaxRedirect=1' % redirect
```

Comment: Multiple ways, loop over your own urls or check the root path of the request. If the root path != your root path its probably external.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best option, but you can compare [request.get_host()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) with `response['Location']` (or [response.url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect.url) in django dev version).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, actually solution added above.